# WordPress: How can set all big title in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have error in permalink, I have post that title is big like :-

```
Tesla will reportedly build its EV battery 'giga factory' in Nevada
```

Now when open the post in my site i see permalink like :-

```
www.domain.com/tesla-will-reportedly-build-its-ev--batter
```

But i set the permalink structure is `/%postname%/`.

Why its not get all post title ?

Comment: wordpress have 200 character limit to generate url

Comment: mmm but my title less than 200 char

Comment: have you try the following answer code pasted...........

Comment: show me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) in functions.php on line 991

Comment: try the code which i have pasted

Answer (score 0):

```
 sanitize_title() is the function which is restricting the number of character for permalink.

  //  remove standard hook
 remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes' );

  // add custom hook 
 add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wptris_sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );
function wptris_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context =   'display' ) {
$title = strip_tags($title);
// Preserve escaped octets.
$title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
// Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
$title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
// Restore octets.
$title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

if (seems_utf8($title)) {
    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
        $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
    }
    $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000); // <--- here is the trick!
}

$title = strtolower($title);
$title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
$title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

if ( 'save' == $context ) {
    // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
    $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

        // Strip these characters entirely
        $title = str_replace( array(
        // iexcl and iquest
        '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
        // angle quotes
        '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
        // curly quotes
        '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
        '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
        // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
        '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
        // grave accent, acute accent, macron, caron
        '%cc%80', '%cc%81', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
    ), '', $title );

    // Convert times to x
    $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
}

$title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
$title = trim($title, '-');

return $title;
```

}

Comment: its show me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) in functions.php on line 991

Answer (score 0):

```
// first of all lets remove standard hook
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes' );

// add our custom hook 
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );
function wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000); // <--- here is the trick!
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

    if ( 'save' == $context ) {
        // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
        $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

            // Strip these characters entirely
            $title = str_replace( array(
            // iexcl and iquest
            '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
            // angle quotes
            '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
            // curly quotes
            '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
            '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
            // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
            '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
            // grave accent, acute accent, macron, caron
            '%cc%80', '%cc%81', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
        ), '', $title );

        // Convert times to x
        $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
    }

    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: i try add post with title like `Tesla will reportedly build its EV battery 'giga factory' in Nevada` the url must be like title

Comment: what you want you does not want same or want same

Comment: when write post more than 200 Char its not set it in url